# body tag wrapped in div precludes animate scrollTop

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, scrolltop

The forum I'm using has some kind of block on the body tag, where anything you try to target with jquery never gets found. My hacky solution was to wrap the body in a container, like so:

```
$('html').find('body').wrap('<div id="bodywrap"></div>');
var $bodywrap = $('#bodywrap'); 
$bodywrap.doStuff(); // now I can manipulate the DOM all I want
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <div id="bodywrap">
        <body>...</body>
    </div>
</html>
```

It's a hacky solution but it worked, so whatever, I'm fine with it even though it's not exactly a 'politically correct' solution.

The only problem that has come up so far is that I'm unable to use any animate scrollTop stuff. Normally I would use something like this -

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:333}, 500);
```

...but now that the DOM has this body wrapper, it's not working. Doing this doesn't work either:

```
$('html, #bodywrap').animate({scrollTop:333}, 500);
```

Ideas?